# Design Patterns Video Tutorial

Tags: design-patterns

Where can I find a good video/screencast tutorial that will explain and give code examples on Object oriented design patterns - ideally using c#?

Many thanks

Answer (score 11):

I have found many good videos on software design (and other programming topics) at [dimecasts](https://web.archive.org/web/20160920081137/http://dimecasts.net:80/). They are all quite short (~10 minutes).

There is a [design patterns](https://web.archive.org/web/20160906181233/http://dimecasts.net:80/Casts/ByTag/Design%20Patterns) tag.

---

Note:

dimecasts.net seems to be dead now - the links have been updated to archive.org, though the videos seem to require flash (I was unable to check if those are still up).

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment?

Comment: Found something at http://www.newthinktank.com/videos/design-patterns-tutorial/ but it is Java based :)

Comment: @Oded +1. I don't know why has it been down voted. Nice links.. Thanks. Although I'm a Ruby programmer, I'll try to get something out from this also.

Comment: @Oded your link to design patterns tag yields 404 error.  The link to dimecasts gives me 403 error "you don't have permission" :-(

Comment: @avner - unfortunate - looks like it hasn't been updated in a couple of years and has since died. I've updated the links to archive.org - those still work, though I don't know if the video will.

Comment: Thanks @Oded.  This seems to work including the video.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to video-tuts [VTC](http://www.vtc.com/) is a good choice.

[Here](http://www.vtc.com/products/Design-Patterns-tutorials.htm) is the link of design pattern videos.

Answer (score 1):

I found this new small series on youtube, he provides some very simple examples, and gets to the point quickly, and it's easy to understand! It's awesome.

[Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94t2ayF1l3o&list=UUvaaYdsdMw_PXUsgTHzyFNQ&index=8&feature=plcp)

Answer (score 0):

You can find some video tutorials about design patterns [here](http://www.softwaretrainingtutorials.com/design-patterns.php).
But i think that the best way to learn would be to start writing small projects in which you'll implement different design patterns that you learn. You could use some books for this. 
I recommend one like [this](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527730) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1861008740), they are both about design patterns applied in c#.